# Efficient way to sort a list by several comparators in Java

Tags: java, sorting, optimization, performance

*Sorry for my English.*

I have something like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    private List<T> elements;
    private List<Comparator<T>> comparators;

    public SomeClass(List<T> elements) {
        this.elements = elements;
        this.comparators = new ArrayList<Comparator<T>>();
    }

    public void addComparator(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        comparators.add(comparator);
    }

    public List<T> getSortedElements() {
        return sorted(new ArrayList<T>(elements));
    }

    // !!! At the moment I use very inefficient way
    // !!! to sort elements by several comparators.
    private List<T> sorted(List<T> toSort) {
        // I need to use stable sort.
        // Collections.sort(...) is guaranteed to be stable
        for (Comparator<T> comparator : comparators) {
            Collections.sort(toSort, comparator);
        }
        return toSort;
    }
}
```

Can I optimize `sorted() method` ?  Maybe this can be done using a single sorting of collection by using combined comparator? (instead of sorting several times with each of comparators)

(But I have to use a stable sort, and last-added comparators have a higher priority than comparators added at the beginning)

**UPDATE:**

I use sorting by several comparators to sort elements by different attributes (for example, by priority, name, etc.)

Comment: Why are you attempting to sort `toSort` this way?  Only the last `Collections.sort` wins.  Are you attempting to use multiple `Comparators` to perform a "sort by this, then that, then the other"?

Comment: What's the point of sorting by more than one comparator?

Comment: I want to sort a list of some objects by several attributes. For example, sort by price, by name, etc.

Comment: That can be done with a single comparator.

Comment: You just need to mention one `Comparator` and your `compare` method should consider all the properties that you want to sort. You somehow vary your order of properties in you `compare` method based on the need

Comment: `For example, sort by price, by name` if you are sorting by price, then you are not sorting by name. Or are you talking about case where for example "element with same prices should be sorted by name"?

Comment: @Pschemo yes. And that's why I wrote that I need stable sorting.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you sort it the way you are doing, subsequent sorts completely discard the sorting done by previous sorts.

I think what you're wanting is to say something like "if the first comparator finds them equal, sort by the next". You can do that like this:

```
class SomeClass<T> {
    private List<T> elements;
    private List<Comparator<T>> comparators;

    private final Comparator<T> combined = new Comparator<T>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(T e1, T e2) {
            for(Comparator<T> c : comparators) {
                int result = c.compare(e1, e2);

                if(result != 0)
                    return result;
            }

            return 0;
        }
    };

    ...

    private List<T> sorted(List<T> toSort) {
        Collections.sort(toSort, combined);

        return toSort;
    }
}
```

Comment: I need efficient way to do what the `sorted() method` does. In other words I need to get the same result which this method returns.

Comment: @leonidandand What do you mean by efficient? `Collections#sort` uses merge sort which is pretty efficient. What I showed above only runs the sort a single time. The only way it can be more efficient is by using an even faster sorting algorithm (marginal) or optimizing your comparators.

Comment: @leonidandand, Radiodef's answer is how my answer works under the covers. It's just a question of whether you'd rather depend on Guava or reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 5):

Using [Guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v16.0/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#compound%28java.lang.Iterable%29):

```
static <T> Comparator<T> compound(List<Comparator<T>> comparators)
{
    return Ordering.compound(comparators);
}
```

Given a pair of elements, the comparators in the given list are tried one after the other, in order, until one produces a non-zero result, which is returned, or there are no comparators left, in which case zero is returned.